# The runtime constant in forward declaration

Tags: nim-lang

How do we do runtime constant in forward definition/declaration by any way around (tried hard not work on using let)

```
let n :int

proc m : int =
 let i=1
 var u=n+i

n=m()
```

error for this or for other varied ones:

```
Error: 'let' symbol requires an initialization

Error: redefinition of 'n'; previous
```

... etc
Please solve it out, thanks before

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say what you are trying to do with this code, a `let` variable is treated as a constant, so it can't be modified, but presumably your intent is to use the variable as a sort of counter to increase itself and presumably reassign `n` multiple times by calling `m()`? If you remove the `n` from the `proc` you can write the code like:

```
proc m : int =
 let i=1
 var u=0+i

let n :int = m()
```

So if you actually want `n` to be mutable, there's no problem using a `var`:

```
var n :int

proc m : int =
 let i=1
 var u=n+i
 u

n=m()
echo n
```

Note that I had to add `u` as a last line to the `m` proc, because otherwise you were returning nothing and the assignment to `n` would always be zero, which is the default value for the implicit `result` variable inside a proc that returns something. You can verify this by repeating the `n=m()` assignment before the last `echo`.